# PNRP Global_ stuck on Alone

Tags: .net, cmd, p2p, pnrp

I have two installations of Windows 7. a 64bit version on my hard disk, and a 32bit version installed as a bootable VHD.

on my the 64bit version, I can't get my PNRP Global_ cloud out of Alone state.

on my the 32bit version, I can get it in Active state by registering a peer however I can't resolve a friends peer, maybe I misunderstood how it's done?

However, my 64bit version is what I use for development so I need to get PNRP working under that. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left this open long enough, after a lot of research and failing in solving the problem, I simply formatted windows.

This solved my problem, though it wasn't an ideal solution, I will accept this answer for now but if someone can post a better one in the future I will mark that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether usually the problem revolves around either Teredo or IPv6 connectivity. I was having the same issue here and my problem was that I had 2 interfaces with IPv6 addresses, one of them had no routes to the internet. Once I disabled that one my connectivity came straight back.